# Jquery not loading the map in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the jquery to load the Google Maps. The map doesn't load the right location until I refresh the page many times.

Here's the script:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                labelContent: address,
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: {
                    opacity: 1.0
                }
            });
        } else {
            //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
initialize();
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Are you calling `initialize()` inside a load handler? If you call it before `id=map` exists nothing will happen

Comment: I didn't get any error in display. I only have to refresh it many time.

Comment: the div id=map is placed before this code.

Comment: We are going to see more code to be able to figure it out.  At this point we can only guess.  Please create a [mcve] (edit the question and add more code to it) - Welcome to StackOverflow